# Can applications subscribe to messages of certain types only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an application which makes changes to different entities. Other applications need to know about these changes.

Is there a way to push change notifications to a single AWS SQS and :

1. have applications to subscribe to message with certain properties only
2. and "mark" messages as read by a certain subscriber?

Essentially, what I'd like to avoid is to create many message queues. A single queue would be enough, and the idea would be that applications would subscribe to certain types of messages. The message queue should be only hand out a single message to a single application once.

Is this doable with AWS SQS?

Comment: Not inbuilt to SQS but possible using SNS & SQS - your only-once requirement also requires FIFO queues if you're not handling any possible duplicates (which do occur rarely at huge amounts within your application). Take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/filter-messages-published-to-topics/ - does that help?

Comment: Eventbridge and it's rules might give you what you need? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html

Comment: Yes, OK - so I'd probably have to set up a single SNS and then have different SQS'es to subscribe to different topics (message "characteristics"). In the end, I'd probably end up with one SQS per subscriber.

Comment: There is no subscriptions to SQS. Do you mean SNS?

Comment: @Marcin that's the question really, and the answer seems to be a combination of SNS + SQS.